# my anaconda on windows10 does not recognize levenshtein module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, levenshtein-distance

I use anaconda on my Windows10 and checked 'python-levenshtein' has been installed by typing 'conda list'. When I run my code edited by jupyter notebook, the error comes out that no levenshtein module. Other modules are all working just fine. so what should I do to make the thing work?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the version of python of your environment, also the command line you used to install your library and the code you wrote.

Comment: version information. conda 4.8.1, python 3.7.6, python-levenshtein 0.12.0, jupyter notebook 6.0.1, and command line was probably `conda install -c conda-forge python-levenshtein`

Comment: my code is `import Levenshtein

def normalized_distance(text0, text1):
    dist = Levenshtein.distance(text0, text1)
    max_len = max(len(text0), len(text1))
    return dist / max_len`

Comment: error message on my jupyter notebook is `ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c08e741a9b3b> in <module>
----> 1 import Levenshtein
      2 
      3 def normalized_distance(text0, text1):
      4     dist = Levenshtein.distance(text0, text1)
      5     max_len = max(len(text0), len(text1))

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Levenshtein'`

Comment: Thanks for the information. When you are in your conda env, when you do a `conda list`do you see your lenvenshtein package? Also, be sure you are in the same conda env when you installed your package and execute your script! Please see [how to activate your conda env](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)

Comment: When I type `conda list` I can see `python-levenshtein        0.12.0          py37hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge`

Comment: what i feel strange is that i cannot see `open with jupyter notebook' selection on my anaconda navigator when i chose py37 as my env.

Comment: py37 is my env name. i can see '(py37) C:\Users\user_name>jupyter notebook' and  and `(py37) C:\Users\user_name>conda list` that shows levenshtein above on my windows prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Imports are case-sensitive, and levenshtein's module name is unconventionally capitalized. So,

```
import Levenshtein
```

works, but

```
import levenshtein
```

doesn't.